# Any real sequence can be written as ratio of the terms of two bounded sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to prove the following:

> If $(c_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ is any real sequence. I should show that there exist two bounded sequences $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, (b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$
>   such that $c_n = \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $.

So my guess was that:

if $c_n$ is bounded I can say $a_n=c_n, b_n=1$

if $c_n$ is not bounded $a_n=1, b_n=\frac{1}{c_n}$

So my questions are:

- Can or should I proof first that if $a_n,b_n$ is bounded that $c_n$ is also bounded?
- Because if $c_n$ is a $0$ sequence I have a division by $0$

Thank you.

Comment: By "limited" do you mean "bounded" or "such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists"?

Comment: I mean that they have a supremum (infimum).

Comment: Ok. It is "bounded".

Answer (score 0):

- It is not true that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N},(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\text{ limited}\implies\left(\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}\text{ limited}$. For instance, consider $a_n=1,\ b_n=\frac1n$
- In fact, you grasped one part of the idea, but not the other one, which, allows you to use it effectively. To complete it, set a given number $u>0$. Observe that, for the values of $n$ such that $\lvert c_n\rvert>u$, you have $-\frac1u<\frac1{c_n}<\frac1u$. So that subsequence is bounded. On the other hand, when $\lvert c_n\rvert\le u$... Well that's bounded.

So, what's an educated guess of a *piece-wise definition* of $a_n$ and $b_n$ ?

Comment: For the definition of $a_n, b_n$ bounded I would use:

$a_n \le S_a$ and $b_n \le S_b$ => $a_n + b_n \le S_a + S_b$

Comment: And the definition for the sequence $|a_n - a| < \epsilon_a, |b_n - b| < \epsilon_b$

Comment: @flow Are those strings of symbols supposed to be related to the problem at hand?

Comment: I don't understand, thank you anyway.